# iOS Safari & Chrome crash and reload when I try to do many file uploads in React app

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-chrome, safari, upload

I'm having a very weird issue in iOS. There's a page in my React app where users can upload pictures to cloudinary. Whenever I select more than 6 photos, the app crashes and reloads. It happens in both Safari and Chrome.

I believe it has to do something with the browser cache hitting a limit but I could be wrong.

I was originally using react-dropzone and thought it was an issue with the package so I switched to use-file-picker, the API is very similar so my code remained pretty much the same. The issue kept happening.

Before doing any change, I was just looping through the accepted files and calling a fetch (POST) for each file to upload it to cloudinary. This was inside a Promise.all().

I thought it was due to making all the 7+ requests at the same time so I added a promisified setTimeout so each request is made every 650 milliseconds. Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue either. That's when I started thinking this might be a browser issue.

The following snippet is where I'm currently doing the upload, with the 650 milliseconds delay between calls. Once again, the issue also happened before I added the delay between calls.

The reason I'm doing a separate fetch per file is because cloudinary doesn't have a bulk upload endpoint. They do support bulk uploads but only if I use their snippet, which I don't want to use due to its UI design.

This doesn't seem to be an issue with Cloudinary as I can upload much more files concurrently from my PC. Also, while debugging the iOS Safari, I don't see any failed request. The page just reloads and quickly shows a message that says "The page was reloaded due to an error". The upload calls then hang indefinitely.

I hope you can help me with this one!

```
    const tasks = acceptedFiles.map(async (file, idx) => {
        const delay = 650 * idx;
        return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("file", file);
        
          formData.append("tags", userId); 

          await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, delay));

          const data = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_BASE_URL}`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: formData,
            }
          ).then((r) => r.json());

          const res = data.secure_url;
          resolve(res);
        });
      });

    const promises = await Promise.all(tasks);
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up fixing this issue by replacing react-dropzone with Uppy. Given that react-dropzone isn't really an uploader and [Uppy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uppy) is, it turned out it has much better file upload handling out of the box.